# osmdroid, set a custom icon in a mapview

Tags: android, osmdroid

My App is using a local service, that provides changing locations.
These locations are added to my ArrayList:

```
static List<Location> weg = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

The `WegAnsehenActivity` now shows the path connecting the points.

My goal: I want to change the icon on the path for the last current point

completion: I want to change the green arrow on the last position

My problem: how can I achieve this ?

```
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;
.
.
.
public class WegAnsehenActivity extends Activity {
  MapView mapView;
  IMapController mapController;
  MyLocationNewOverlay o;
  Paint paint;
  PathOverlay overlay;
  //filled by the local service, method onLocationChanged
  static List<Location> weg = new ArrayList<Location>();

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    //false keeps the mapView from loading online tiles using network connection!!!
    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);//true);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    overlay = new PathOverlay(Color.BLUE, this);
    overlay.setPaint(paint);
    o = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
    if (weg.size() >= 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i < weg.size(); i++) {
        if (i==weg.size()-1) {
          mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(weg.get(i).getLatitude(), weg.get(i).getLongitude()));
        }
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(weg.get(i));
        overlay.addPoint(point);
      }
      mapView.getOverlayManager().add(overlay);
      o.enableMyLocation(); //shows a green arrow I want to replace
      mapView.getOverlays().add(o);
      mapView.postInvalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Please help!

Regards Wicki

Comment: In my experience,  osmdroid doesn't let you change icons of existing points.  The only solution is to remove and remove and add it again

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is sub-class MyLocationNewOverlay, and set your own bitmaps (mPersonBitmap and mDirectionArrowBitmap) in your constructor.

Or you can try to use this constructor:

```
public MyLocationNewOverlay(IMyLocationProvider myLocationProvider, 
    MapView mapView, ResourceProxy resourceProxy)
```

and define your own "ResourceProxy".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advices.
Now I have found a solution.
I have commented out the instruction "o.enableMyLocation();", that is responsible for standard icon.
It follows the replacement for the last 4 instructions:

```
mapView.getOverlayManager().add(overlay);
// o.enableMyLocation(); //shows the green-arrow-marker (my own position)
mapView.getOverlays().add(o);
setMarker(); //set an own marker
mapView.postInvalidate();
.
.
void setMarker() {
  Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
  ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> overlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
          new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(), marker, null,
          new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this));
  // gc: last GeoPoint
  OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(null, null, gc);
  overlay.addItem(item);
  mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
}
```

Regards Wicki