# How to extends ResourceProxy interface in osmdroid?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

yea, i know, another thread about changing icons in osmdroid.
But there isn't any good explanation available !

I made lot of research and it is a [frequently asked topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669305/osmdroid-set-a-custom-icon-in-a-mapview/32694269). Why not make a clear answer at this point for all user who need to specify their own resources ?

All stuff available is to "[Have a look at ResourceProxy.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669305/osmdroid-set-a-custom-icon-in-a-mapview/32694269#32694269)" or "Pass the bitmap to constructor". No way, it doesn't work for me, I don't even know how a simple interface could find my drawable in my res folder ! I tried to pass some .PNG files with the same names as osmdroid (like "person.png") but when I run the app I have still the default resource.

Can someone explain **clearly** how to write "**our own ResourceProxy**" step by step ? [Not brievely like that because I followed the steps and didn't manage to success.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615849/changing-osmdroids-mylocationoverlay-marker/18616026#18616026)

I know that
[osmdroid was fixed recently](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/99#issuecomment-112968897) in github but the .aar is older than the fix. Here you can find the
[Resource Proxy class.](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/ResourceProxy.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create in an instance of the MapView, you need to pass in a reference to a implementation of "ResourceProxy". By default, it loads the "DefaultResourceProxyImpl". To override, create a new class that extends DefaultResourceProxyImpl and then you can override getBitmap and getDrawable. There is actually is an example that overrides the DefaultResourceProxyImpl here:

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/ResourceProxyImpl.java

Just for you, I'm working on including such an example with the osmdroid example app. It's going to look something like this

```
 public class CustomResourceProxy extends DefaultResourceProxyImpl {

      private final Context mContext;
      public CustomResourceProxy(Context pContext) {
           super(pContext);
        mContext = pContext;
      }

      @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(final bitmap pResId) {
        switch (pResId){
                case person:
                     //your image goes here!!!
                     return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),org.osmdroid.example.R.drawable.sfgpuci);

           }
           return super.getBitmap(pResId);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(final bitmap pResId) {
        switch (pResId){
                case person:
                     //your image goes here!!!
                     return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(org.osmdroid.example.R.drawable.sfgpuci);
           }
           return super.getDrawable(pResId);
    }

 }
```

Edit: done
See https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/CustomResourceProxy.java

Edit: Edit:
Wiki updated, see 
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library